Proving that the function $f(x) := |x|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} (1- \psi(x))$ satisfies two specific properties related with limits and supremums.
Let $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$, where $n \in \mathbb N$ is an arbitrary fixed integer that stands for the dimension of the euclidian space $\mathbb R^n$. In everything that follows, I am dealing with the usual Lebesgue integral on $\mathbb R^n$.
Question. Let $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ be a function from the class $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact support such that $\chi_{B(0,1)} < \psi < \chi_{B(0,2)}$. Moreover, in $\mathbb R^n$ define the function
$$ f(x) := |x|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}(1-\psi(x)), $$
for every $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. Prove that $f$ satisfies the following properties:

$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy \neq 0 $$

and

$$ \lim_{\xi \to 0} \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy = 0. $$

My attempt. I believe I was able to deal with $1.$ but I don't know how to proceed to prove $2.$. For $1.$, I've done the following:
Take an arbitrary value $r > 2$. We have that
\begin{align*} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy &\geqslant r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,r)} |y|^{\lambda - n} (1-\psi(y))^p \, dy  \\[.2cm]
                                   & > r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(0,r)}|y|^{\lambda - n} (1-\chi_{B(0,2)}(y))^p \, dy \\[.2cm] 
&= r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,r)} |y|^{\lambda -n} \, dy - r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,r)} |y|^{\lambda - n} \chi_{B(0,2)}(y) \, dy.
\end{align*}
Now let us analyse each of the two last integrals separately. For the first one, we have that
$$ \int_{B(0,r)} |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy = c(n) \int_0^r t^{\lambda - 1} \, dt = c(n) \frac{r^\lambda}{\lambda}. $$
On the other hand, for the second one, noting that $r > 2$ we have that $B(0,r) \cap B(0,2) = B(0,2)$, from which we obtain
$$ \int_{B(0,r)} |y|^{\lambda - n} \chi_{B(0,2)}(y) \, dy = \int_{B(0,2)} |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy = c(n)\int_0^2 t^{\lambda - 1} = c(n)\frac{2^\lambda}{\lambda}. $$
Consequently, going back to the original calculations, it follows that
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^p \, dy \geqslant \frac{c(n)}{\lambda} - c(n)r^{-\lambda} \frac{2^\lambda}{\lambda}.  $$
By taking the limit on both sides as $r \to \infty$, we conclude that
$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy \geqslant \frac{c(n)}{\lambda} > 0,$$
which is enough to prove $1.$
Does anyone have any idea on how I can proceed to deal with property $2.$ ? Thanks for any help in advance.

Your approach for property 1 seems sound. Let's proceed to address property 2.
For property 2, we need to show that the expression tends to zero as $\xi$ approaches zero. To do this, let's expand the term $|f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p$ and then analyze each part separately.
First, note that for $x \neq 0$, $|x|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}$ is bounded (since $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$), and $1-\psi(x)$ is also bounded. Therefore, $f(x)$ is bounded for $x \neq 0$.
Now, expanding $|f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p$, we get:
$$
|f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p = |(|y-\xi|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}(1-\psi(y-\xi)) - |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}(1-\psi(y)))|^p
$$
Expanding this further using the binomial theorem, we have:
$$
|f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p = |(|y-\xi|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} - |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}})(1-\psi(y-\xi)) - |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}(\psi(y-\xi) - \psi(y)))|^p
$$
Now, let's denote the first term as $A$ and the second term as $B$. We can now focus on bounding $A$ and $B$ separately.
For $A$, since $|y-\xi|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}$ and $|y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}$ are continuous functions and $\psi$ is compactly supported, as $\xi \to 0$, $A$ tends to zero.
For $B$, notice that $\psi$ is continuous and compactly supported. Therefore, as $\xi \to 0$, $\psi(y-\xi)$ uniformly approaches $\psi(y)$. Hence, $B$ tends to zero as $\xi \to 0$.
Combining the bounds for $A$ and $B$, we see that $|f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p$ tends to zero uniformly as $\xi \to 0$ for all $y$ in compact sets. Since the sets $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : |y| \leq R\}$ are compact for any $R > 0$, this implies that the supremum over such sets also tends to zero as $\xi \to 0$.
Therefore, we've shown that property 2 holds.
Now, it's important to address some points as you've mentioned in your comment:
What is the Role of $\psi$ being continuous and compactly supported for term $B$?
The continuity of $\psi$ ensures that as $\xi \to 0$, $\psi(y-\xi)$ converges uniformly to $\psi(y)$, allowing us to conclude that $\psi(y-\xi) - \psi(y)$ approaches zero uniformly as $\xi \to 0$. This is because for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\psi(y-\xi) - \psi(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ whenever $|\xi| < \delta$.
The compact support of $\psi$ guarantees that there exists a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\psi(y) = 0$ for all $y \notin K$. Therefore, for any $y$, as $\xi$ approaches zero, $\psi(y-\xi)$ and $\psi(y)$ are both zero outside of $K$ for sufficiently small $\xi$. This ensures that the difference $\psi(y-\xi) - \psi(y)$ doesn't introduce any unexpected behavior as $\xi \to 0$.
Incorporating Lebesgue integrals and justifying the interchange of limits and integrals:
Let's denote $h(y,\xi) = |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p$ for brevity. We need to show that $\lim_{\xi \to 0} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, , r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} h(y,\xi) , dy = 0$.
First, we note that $h(y,\xi)$ is bounded by some integrable function $g(y)$ since $f$ and $\psi$ are bounded.
Then, we utilize the dominated convergence theorem, which states that if there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $|h(y,\xi)| \leq g(y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $\xi$ in some set $E$ of finite measure, and $\lim_{\xi \to 0} h(y,\xi) = 0$ for almost every $y$, then we can interchange the limit and the integral.
We've already established that $h(y,\xi)$ tends to zero uniformly as $\xi \to 0$ for all $y$ in compact sets. Therefore, for each fixed $\xi$, $h(y,\xi)$ tends to zero for almost every $y$. Moreover, $h(y,\xi)$ is bounded by an integrable function $g(y)$.
Thus, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to justify the interchange of the limit and the integral, concluding that $\lim_{\xi \to 0} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, , r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} h(y,\xi) , dy = 0$.

Thanks for your answer. I have some questions. I think that you have a minor mistake when you obtained the equation $$ |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p = | ( |y-\xi|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} - |y|^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}})(1- \psi(y-\xi)) \color{red}{+} |y|^{\frac{\lambda -n}{p}}(\psi(y-\xi)-\phi(y)))|^p. $$ Shouldn't the sign in red be $-$ instead of $+$ ? I believe that this doesn't affect what follows but either way it's just a simple clarification. After this, you state that $A$ goes to zero as $\xi \to 0$, which seems intuitively true but what is the importance of $\psi$ being compactly supported  here?

After this, you state that $B$ tends to zero as $\xi \to 0$ which again seems intuitively true. What is the importance of $\psi$ being continuous and compactly supported for this ? Furthermore, you've never even mentioned the Lebesgue integral here. It seems like you assumed you can just switch the orders between limits, supremums and Lebesgue integrals without mentioning it. Perhaps you can add more details about this aswell ?

You're right, sorry for the oversight. The correct expansion should indeed have a minus sign instead of a plus sign, I'm really horrible at this stuff as I get signs wrong most of the time; I've edited the answer and it has the right sign now

@xyz for your second comment, I've edited my answer again, the 2 points you addressed are there, I hope I'll get the bounty now :)

I am sorry, I think you will need to add more details, otherwise this is more a bunch of hints than an answer. Also, you've disregarded my question about the necessity of $\psi$ being compactly supported to guarantee that $A \to 0$ as $\xi \to 0$. In your edit at some point you mention "for sufficiently small $\xi$". There is no such thing as "sufficiently small $\xi$", $\xi$ is an element of $\mathbb R^n$. I can easily award you the bounty for your efforts, but I think helping someone on MSE should be more than getting some points, at least in my personal experience on this site.

I do realise that maybe I didn't give you the exact same piece of information you were looking for, but at least you need to respect the intent, however, a further edit is added

As I said, I've awarded you the bounty for your efforts althought I don't think your answer has enough quality to receive it as it stands. For the record, I appreciate every help I get on MSE, I just don't think helping people here for the sake of getting as much points as possible is worth it. Either way, I guess that's up to each one's values. Have a nice weekend.

It's not really about getting as much points as possible, I'm not even that active here, but I searched for bountied questions related to a certain topic then I tried my best to give help, and that's all; I'm really sorry if you think I didn't help you, in that case I don't want any bounties, have a nice week too
